# converts all columns of datatable in to string list

Tags: c#, linq

I want to convert columns of a datatable into string list

I have found many links on stackoverflow but that is not meeting my requirement

I tried few options

```
List<string> lstColumnList1 = dtAllRows.Columns.Cast<string>().ToList();3
List<string> lstColumnList =  dtAllRows.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x[0].ToString()).ToList();
```

I dont want to run loop of columns
But noting working. Please help.

Comment: what you mean saying convert all columns of datatable into strings list?

Answer (score 9):

To get column names

```
var columns = table.Columns
                   .Cast<DataColumn>()
                   .Select(x => x.ColumnName)
                   .ToList();
```

If you mean first column's values use this

```
var rowValues = table.AsEnumerable()
                     .Select(x => x.Field<string>("YourColumn"))
                     .ToList();
```

Comment: Do you even need the `.Cast`? `.Columns` is typed so I don't think it's needed.

Comment: @Tobberoth It is required. IIRC it doesn't implement `IEnumerable<DataColumn>` it just implements non generic `IEnumerable`.

Comment: @MAkela you are making people here so **CONFUSED**. your question title says **converts all columns of datatable** but converting one column also works for you???

Comment: @SriramSakthivel the downvotes for the OP explain all. You're the answerer receiving this comment `well worked thanks :)` from the OP, so you can feel happy with him.

Comment: @KingKing Am not sure about which part in my answer helped OP. Am not sure yet. I answered based on OP's attempt `dtAllRows.Columns.Cast<string>().ToList()` and `dtAllRows.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x[0].ToString())` as well. You can say your opinion, critics etc but why **BOLD**? without bold also anybody can understand. Again this is my opinion only. You may take it may not. It is not that I got appreciation from OP, so I support OP. am talking in general.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel he may not know how to do it, the last sentence in his question is `I dont want to run loop of columns`, that means he really wants to convert all columns.

Comment: @KingKing Oh.. am sorry I overlooked it. and completely am confused now what actually OP need

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var columnsList = dtAllRows.AsEnumerable()
                  .SelectMany(row=>dtAllRows.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                                            .Select(col=>Convert.ToString(row[col])))
                  .ToList();
//Example:
//A1   B1
//A2   B2
//-> List<string> {"A1","B1","A2","B2"}
```